# "Show that the limit $ \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2x^2y^3}{x^4+y^6} $ does not exist."

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2x^2y^3}{x^4+y^6} $$

My reasoning after reading the textbook: Direct substitution wouldn't work since it would lead to the indeterminate form $0/0$. We can examine the values of $f$ along parabolic curves that end at $(0,0)$. Along $y=kx^2, x\neq0$, the function has the value

$$ \frac{2k^3x^4}{1+k^6x^8}. $$

So, if $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along $y=x^2$, then $k = 1$, and the limit is $\frac{2x^4}{1+x^8}$. If $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis, then $k=0$, and the limit is $0$.
Is this correct and/or is there another way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: As $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$, $\frac{2x^4}{1+x^8}$ approaches $0$ as well.

Comment: Suggestion: try $y\propto x^{2/3}$. Why? By the AM-GM inequality, $2x^2y^3 \leq x^4+y^6$, with equality iff $x^2 = y^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DMcMor observed, unfortunately your reasoning is incorrect as
$$\frac{2x^4}{1 + x^8} \to 0$$
as $x \to 0$. But the idea is correct: you want to find two paths through $(0, 0)$ whose limits are different. You might consider the paths $y = x^{2/3}$ and $y = x$, for example. Usually, in problems where we want to show the limit doesn't exist, the strategy for picking two paths is to first find a path where the numerator's degree is higher than the denominator's degree (happening here with $y = x$) --- in which case the limit becomes zero --- and then find a second path through which the denominator and numerator have the same degree (happening here with $y = x^{2/3}$ --- in which case the limit will be nonzero.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! Anyways, thanks a lot for this -- really helpful.